# How does brain makes descisons?

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience

I have recently started studying about brain network analysis, Does brain makes decisions based on neuron connections? ex: If say 10 neurons were there, if I see pen to recognize that as pen does the neurons connect in pattern? so when ever they connect in that pattern they recognize as pen? is that the way its working? or I miss understood?

Comment: Something like that, yes.  But as-is, this question is far too broad for this forum, the title does not match the body of the question, and there is no evidence of any background context, so I am going to close it.  You can also check out this question instead: [Computational model of biological object recognition](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/5267/7001).